# Why MediaPlayer getDuration() method return -1 on low quality audio?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-api-levels

I updated my app android **API-23 to API-28** now `MediaPlayer getDuration()` method **return -1**, in api-23 getDuration method working fine but in latest api having issue. when using **low quality (i.e 16kbs)** of audio. but same time when i use **high quality (64kbs to 192kbs)** working fine.

```
MediaPlayer mp;
// 128kbs working fine in my app 
mp.setDataSource(http://www.villopim.com.br/android/Music_02.mp3);
// return actual time    
mp.getDuration();

// 16kbs working fine in my app 
mp.setDataSource(http://topappstopgames.com/appsdata/islamic/sn002.mp3);
// return -1    
mp.getDuration();
```

So how to resolve this issue in latest api.

Comment: ok dear @zoe i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shift to [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/soonsam123/UsagesOfExoplayer) now its working.

Answer (score 1):

from the **documentation**

> the duration in milliseconds, if no duration is available (for example, if streaming live content), -1 is returned.

but shouldn't you use this

```
mp.getDuration();
```

instead of this :

```
mediaPlayer.getDuration();
```

?

Comment: dear content is available on server but always return -1,  i don't know why.
i user mp.getDuration() now question is updated.

Comment: as said in the documentation , no duration is available

Comment: i shared link in question. its works in previous api but now not working